# Using lists with re (Or how to delete a substring between a list of possible codons)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-re

I'm writing a script to remove open reading frames from a series of genes. I am aware of the `re` module, but I don't quite understand it's proper usage when lists are involved - here is my task:

1. I need to find the start codon `'AUG'` in the gene
2. I then need to find an occurrence of one of 3 possible stop codons which are stored in a list

   `stop_codons = ['TAG', 'TAA', 'TGA']`
3. I then need to delete all other characters between the start and
   stop codon.

I achieved something close with:

```
gene = 'AUGGTAAATTGAUUGUTAUTAUTGTAGTGATGU'
re.sub('AUG.+TAG', '', gene)
```

However I feel that there must be a better way than writing a line for each stop codon and looping through a predefined list would be better form (some mitochondrial genomes and bacterial genomes have alternative start/stop codons and I would like the code to be easily modified to include those codons when appropriate).

How can I achieve this with re?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that `re` tries to match the biggest possible substring. This means that a naive approach will not stop at the first "end" codon but the LAST one:

```
            start                   end1     end2
            vvv                     vvv      vvv
>>> gene = 'AUGGTAAATTGAUUGUTAUTAUTGTAGTGATGUTAGG'
>>> re.sub('AUG.+TAG', '', gene)
'G'
```

Better:

```
>>> re.sub('AUG.+?TAG', '', gene)
'TGATGUTAGG'
```

You can avoid iterating over the string multiple times by using an "A or B" type of expression in the regex, this looks like `(A|B)`. In your example:

```
          start end
            vvv vvv
>>> gene = 'AUGGTAAATTGAUUGUTAUTAUTGTAGTGATGUTAGG'
>>> re.sub('AUG.+?(TAG|TAA|TGA)', '', gene)
'TGATGUTAGG'
```

Comment: Perfect! I was stuck trying to use ```re.sub('AUG.+(TAG|TAA|TGA)?', '', gene)``` last night - I need to brush up on regex syntax!

Comment: """Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems."""

Answer (score 0):

Code below should do what you mean. It looks for occurrence and then prints cut gene without characters between start and stop codon for every item in `stop_codons` list.

```
import re

gene = 'AUGGTAAATTGAUUGUTAUTAUTGTAGTGATGU'
start_codon = 'AUG'
stop_codons = ['TAG', 'TAA', 'TGA']

for stop_codons_item in stop_codons:
  cut_gene = re.sub('(?<=%s).*?(?=%s)' % (start_codon,stop_codons_item), '', gene)
  print(cut_gene)
```

Your code cuts also `start_codon` and `stop_codon` in the output. I don't know if that's what you want to achieve. If so, just replace `cut_gene` variable with your re.sub example line in for loop like this:

```
re.sub(f'{start_codon}.+{stop_codons_item}', '', gene)
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain what ```'(?<=%s).*?(?=%s)' %``` does?

Comment: It's a regular expression, which used with string interpolation (% operator) allows us to find part of string you want to skip. First `%s` refers to `start_codon`, as mentioned later in the string, and second to `stop_codons_item` variable.